# How many V table will be created in the following code?

Tags: c++

```
class base{
public:
    virtual void fn() {

    }
};

class der1 : public base {
    void fn() {

    }
};

class der2 : public der1 {
    virtual void fn() {

    }
};
```

I have another question.In definition of class der1, I have not mention "virtual" while redefining function fn. Has it any effect while creating V table

Comment: If you have another question, you'll probably get better answers for both by asking it separately.

Comment: It could be anything from zero to "infinite".

Comment: I don't understand your question... What V table (there's nothing on what you posted that's called V)?

Comment: @R. Martin: For sure it could not be "infinite", for all resources are finite. "Arbitrarily many" is perhaps the right term. :-)

Comment: @Kerrek, yeah, I know, that's why I scare quoted it.

Comment: @m0skit0: Just google it :) A V-Table is a common mechanism to implement virtual dispatch used in many languages, the V stands for Virtual. It is usually accompanied by a V-Pointer, which is a "hidden" attibute of the class pointing to its V-Table.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, vtable is a compiler/platform specific implementation detail, so there is no general answer.

> I have another question.In definition of class der1, I have not mention "virtual" while redefining function fn. Has it any effect while creating V table

Since the function `fn()` has been defined as `virtual` in the base class, all subclass implementations are also virtual by definition (thus overriding the base class implementation), regardless of whether they are explicitly declared so. So the vtable will contain them (if the specific compiler generates one).

You can easily test this by making `base::fn()` pure virtual. If declaring `der1::fn()` virtual made a difference, you could not instantiate `der1` without it.

Answer (score 3):

So, as the pedantic answers implied: the C++ language does not mention v-tables, it's an implementation details that all major compilers used, as it's relatively simple and very efficient (because it's so used, optimizations are well-known).

With that said, the typical answer is that there will be one v-table per class containing virtual functions. Some may be optimized out, if proved to be unused.

Typically, it could be unnecessary to generate a v-table for an abstract class, as it cannot be instantiated. However calling virtual functions in constructors and destructors is still allowed (though the effects are not always those expected), so compilers usually generate a v-table and simply set the entries to the pure virtual functions to null.

Therefore, your answer is *probably 3*.

The following implies a compiler such as GCC which implements the [Itanium C++ ABI](http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html#vtable).

You can actually verify this `3` by generating a library and dumping the symbols (v-tables and typeinfo symbols are generated for classes with virtual functions):

```
$ nm somelib.so | grep Foo
00000000012a48b0 V _ZTIN3FooE
0000000000e0fca0 V _ZTSN3FooE
00000000012a4620 V _ZTVN3FooE

$ nm somelib.so | grep Foo | c++filt
00000000012a48b0 V typeinfo for Foo
0000000000e0fca0 V typeinfo name for Foo
00000000012a4620 V vtable for Foo
```

The prefixes to look for are `_ZTIN`, `_ZTSN` and `_ZTVN` for (resp.) the `typeinfo`, `typeinfo name` and `vtable`.

Answer (score 2):

There can be no concrete answer for this because Virtualism is left out as an implementation detail of compilers.
The C++ standard does not talk about `vptr` or `vtable` at all.  The answer for this can vary from each compiler to compiler.

Answer (score 1):

> How many V table will be created in the following code?

The question can not be answered.
Nor do you want to know, nor should you care. It makes no difference in how your code is used or works.

> I have another question.

Ok Listening.

> In definition of class der1, I have not mention "virtual" while redefining function fn.

Because the definition of 'void fn()' is exactly the same as in the base class it inherits the virtual attribute of the function it is overriding. Thus it is also virtual.

> Has it any effect while creating V table

There is no way to tell. As V-Table have nothing to do with the C++ language (they are what the compiler does behind the code, if it even uses a V-table (which it may not)).